# ActiveRecord::ValueTooLong with Ruby Gem Mail

Tags: ruby, email

When using the Mail gem to recive an Email, i get sometimes the following error.

```
ActiveRecord::ValueTooLong
```

The part that is causing it is curr_mail.body.decoded. 
How can i get this running on Mysql?

When setting an max Size to the Body everything works fine.

```
curr_mail.body.decoded[5000] 

emails.each do |curr_mail|
        Email.create subject: curr_mail.subject, content: curr_mail.body.decoded,
          from: curr_mail.from.first , to: curr_mail.to.first,  date: curr_mail.date,
             messageId: curr_mail.message_id
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception `ActiveRecord::ValueTooLong` already told you what is wrong. The `content` column in `emails` table is too short for a decoded email body.

Change `content` column type to `text` type or set `content`'s length to a larger number would solve this problem.

Run `rails g migration change_content_of_emails_to_text` to generate a migration file.

You can write something like this in the generated migration file:

```
class ChangeContentOfEmailsToText < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    change_column :emails, :content, :text
  end
end
```

Then run `bundle exec rake db:migrate` command.

Edit:
I just realized this might not be a Rails specific question.
If this is a non-rails project, the idea is same.

Go to mysql console and run:

```
ALTER TABLE emails MODIFY content TEXT;
```